# Where is JsonDateHandler enum gone in ServiceStack version 4.0.5.0 (current Nuget Version)?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I cannot find the `JsonDateHandler` enum in the current Nuget ServiceStack version 4.0.5.0.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes

Renamed `JsonDateHandler` to `DateHandler`

and `JsonPropertyConvention` to `PropertyConvention`

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed the change in the release notes.